# PHP Imagick pdf to image color issue

Tags: php, gd, imagick

I am converting first page of pdf to image : My Code

```
$im = new Imagick();
                    // //die("test");
                    $im->setResolution(200, 200);     //set the resolution of the resulting jpg
                    $im->readImage($cuurentPath . '[0]');    //[0] for the first page
                    $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$im->setCompressionQuality(100);
$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
```

But when output image comes image is too bright

[image]

Upper one is original and lower bright one after converted.Let me know the problem

Comment: I'd suggest testing converting the image directly through ghostscript, which is what is used underneath Imagick. This is likely to be a bug in the version of GS that you're using.

Comment: @Danack : I was doing same.Tried many thing. Brightness ,contrast , color space

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In my case I'm saving in jpg, but i'm getting the same result as you. I suspect it's related to the fact that my input images have 32bit color depth and the output is 24bit. Please write back if you have figured it out already.